# Shared Memory with Docker containers (docker version 1.4.1)

Tags: docker, ipc, shared-memory

I have 1 process that writes to a specific section of shared memory (i.e. "/falcon" )in a docker container.

**Docker image: dockersharedmemory/shmclient**

I have another process that initially creates and reads the same section of shared memory(i.e. "/falcon" ) every second in another docker container.

**Docker image: dockersharedmemory/shmserver**

When I run the two containers using the following commands I am able to read and write in each container respectfully:

`docker run -d -v /dev:/dev dockersharedmemory/shmserver`

`docker run -d -v /dev:/dev dockersharedmemory/shmclient`

When I use the **"--ipc"** option per [documentation](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#ipc-settings) i can't get it to work:

`docker run -d --ipc=host dockersharedmemory/shmserver`

`docker run -d --ipc=host dockersharedmemory/shmclient`

neither

`docker run -d dockersharedmemory/shmserver`

`drunk_feynman`

`docker run -d --ipc=container:drunk_feynman dockersharedmemory/shmclient`

`happy_fermi`

Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8/1.4.1
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.4.1
Server API version: 1.16
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 5bc2ff8/1.4.1

I have a working example now with a combination of the commands on the host by punching huge holes in the container with a combination of volumes and ipc:
`docker run -d -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm --ipc=host dockersharedmemory/shmserver`
`docker run -d -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm --ipc=host dockersharedmemory/shmclient`

Comment: You do understand that Docker is supposed to isolate processes from each other? Not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to share ipc amongst certain containers that rely on shared memory.  The documentation http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#ipc-settings states that it is possible, i am just not able to get it to work using the docker run --ipc option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need -v /dev:/dev
what happens if you do

```
docker run -d -v /dev:/dev --ipc=host dockersharedmemory/shmserver

docker run -d -v /dev:/dev --ipc=host dockersharedmemory/shmclient
```

If you dont mount bind /dev/ then the container cannot see whats inside /dev/ which is where your IPC/shm resides isnt it ?

Comment: The "-v" options mounts the "host" shared memory.  This is a valuable part of the story.  The other part of the story is allocating shared memory on a single container and then accessing the shared memory from a second container.  The documentaton http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#ipc-settings seems to state that you can accomplish this shared memory between containers using the --ipc=container:<name> option.

Comment: so your last option should work. it should do a setns of first container in the second. you can try strace or do a docker inspect, the docker log should give you some clue.  Make sure you look at the /proc/pid/ of the second process.

Comment: `docker run -d dockerclientserver/shmserver`

`sick_goodall`

`docker run -it --ipc container:sick_goodall`

`trusting_rosalind`

i can read the shared memory segment allocated by the process in "sick_goodall" if i run the second process in "sick_goodall."

The second process in "trusting_rosalind" fails to read or write to the shared memory in "sick_goodall."

`docker inspect trusting_rosalind`

`...`
` "IpcMode": "container:sick_goodall",`
`...`

Comment: i am able to create the same shared memory segment name (i.e. "/falcon") in the second container with the `"--ipc container:sick_goodall"` option.  The shared memory does not seem to map with the --ipc option or i am missing something.

Comment: If you do docker run -ti ... /bin/bash (instead of shmclient) you will be able to see if your folder is properly mounted or not.

Comment: my folders are not mounted when i use just the `--ipc`.  Are you proposing that i can mount the drives from one container to another using `-v`?  I thought `-v` was only from the host to container not container to container?

Comment: when i try mounting /dev/shm with `-v /dev/shm` my program writes the shared memory directly under `/dev/` instead of under `/dev/shm`