# IPC communication between Docker containers

Tags: docker, ipc

Is it possible for two separate Docker containers to communicate over a ZMQ IPC socket? If so, how can this be achieved?

For example:

> **Docker Container #1** executes an application that creates a ZMQ Response socket and binds to "ipc://tmp/service_name".
>
> **Docker Container #2** executes an application that creates a ZMQ Request socket and connects to "ipc://tmp/service_name".

The following commands are used to run the applications in two separate docker containers:

```
// Run container #1 (binds to "ipc://tmp/service_name")
docker run --name c1 -it container1

// Run container #2 (connects to "ipc://tmp/service_name")
docker run -it --link c1:container1 --name c2 container2
```

After running the containers, I am not able to establish the ZMQ (IPC) connection. However, I am able to ping container 1 from container 2, and ping container 2 from container 1.

I also tried using the --ipc command, but it did not help:

```
// Run container #1 (binds to "ipc://tmp/service_name")
docker run --name c1 --ipc=host -it container1

// Run container #2 (connects to "ipc://tmp/service_name")
docker run -it --link c1:container1 --ipc=container:c1 --name c2 container2
```

**UPDATE:**
I am able to communicate between two separate Docker containers using a ZMQ TCP socket, but am still unable to communicate using an IPC socket. Is it possible?

Comment: What did you investigate yourself. Did you read for example [this](https://torusware.com/blog/2015/04/optimizing-communications-between-html/) article?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself and report back on what the error is so we actually have something to help with?

Comment: Yes, I did read that article @JeroenHeier . I am going to re-read it and try again to see if there is something that I am missing.

Comment: I updated the original question to show what I tried so far, @AndyShinn

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you seen [Shared Memory with Docker containers (docker version 1.4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173193/shared-memory-with-docker-containers-docker-version-1-4-1)? It sounds like you need to share the volume where the IPC lives and also set `--ipc host`. In your example, it would be something like:

```
# Container #1
docker run -it --name c1 -v /tmp:/tmp --ipc=host container1

# Container #2
docker run -it --name c2 -v /tmp:/tmp --ipc=host container2
```

Comment: I guess the implementation just needs a shared /tmp.  There's no need for `--ipc=host`.  I wouldn't share the host's /tmp nor IPC for security reasons...

Comment: Agreed @RicardoBranco. The following also works:

`docker run -it --name c1 -v /tmp container1

docker run -it --name c2 --ipc=container:c1 --volumes-from c1 container2`

Comment: Then I guess there's no need for `--ipc=...` at all.

Comment: That's true, I didn't need the --ipc-... at all. The /tmp mount is all that was needed...

Comment: It looks like the Docker [ipc setting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#ipc-settings-ipc) is for shared memory, not Unix sockets, which is what [ZMQ uses](http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-ipc).

Comment: If `--ipc=host` is not required and ZMQ only uses Unix sockets, then how does having only the shared `/tmp` work?

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 containers, 2 containers share data to another container, what worked for me is:

```
# container 1
docker run -it --ipc=shareable -v ///tmp --network=host --name node container1

# container 2
docker run -it --ipc=container:node --volumes-from node --network=host --name mdns container2

# container 3
docker run -it --ipc=container:node --volumes-from node --network=host --name connection container3
```

`container1` can get *`pid`* of processes running in `container2` and `container3` and hence get data from the containers.