# Shared-memory-ID is always 0 in a docker container

Tags: c, docker, containers, shared-memory

I want to communicate between two docker containers using shared memory. In both containers, a simple C program is running.

I tried this example and it works very well: [Shared Memory with Docker containers (docker version 1.4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173193/shared-memory-with-docker-containers-docker-version-1-4-1)

However, when I create a new shared memory area, the Shared-Memory-ID is always "0".  I already tried to using a key generated via `ftok()` and also using the key `IPC_PRIVATE`:

```
key_t key = ftok("shmfile", 65);
int shmid = shmget(key, 1024, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

printf("%d \n", shmid);

void *shmdata = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
```

I expect that the ID won't always be 0 and that it will be different when a different key is used.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect that the ID won't always be 0 and that it will be different when a different key is used.

The problem is that your expectation is unfounded.  The ID returned by `shmget()` is a *local* identifier within your program, similar in nature to a file handle.  Sticking with the file analogy, it is the key that plays the role of file name -- the global identifier.  The specifications say only that valid shared-memory IDs are non-negative, but it is natural for them to be numbered from zero.

If you open a second, distinct shared-memory segment at the same time then you should see a different shared-memory ID assigned to it.  Probably 1.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar kind of issue and got fixed by removing ftok() function for creating key. Instead I manually gave value as key.

Eg :

`key_t key = ftok("shmfile", 65);`  ( Old)

`key_t key = 1234;`                 ( Modified )

This fixed my issue :)